# How to control which GTK widgets visible in an expanded row of a tree?

Tags: treeview, gtk, gtk3, togglebutton

I'm building a tree store with GTK3 in C in which there are primary rows that are always displayed, and by clicking on the little triangle icon to the left of a primary row, additional secondary (child) rows expand below the primary. As an example, consider that the primary rows could be directories, and when they're expanded, rows below that show the files in those directories. I'm doing this to allow a user to select primary items to be deleted, while the secondary rows are just informational, telling, for example, what files are in the directory, so they'll know if they really want to delete the whole thing.

To enable selection for deletion, the first column contains a GTK_CELL_RENDERER_TOGGLE, and I have a callback associated with the checkbox toggle. Everything works nicely except for one thing. When the user clicks the little triangle item to expand a row, most of the content of the primary row does not appear in the secondary rows (this is expected and desired), but... the checkbox toggle *does* appear in the first column. Although in a directories/files example that might be meaningful, in my case it makes no sense to think of deleting the content of the secondary rows.

When building the secondary rows, I've tried things like just:

```
gtk_tree_store_set(TS,&J,2,"filename",-1);
```

or

```
gtk_tree_store_set(TS,&J,0,NULL,2,"filename",-1);
```

hoping that NULL would cause the toggle to be suppressed, but to no avail. GTK still displays a checkbox, probably just interpreting the NULL as a zero.

Is there a way to control (and in my case, suppress) display of the toggle? Or more generally, is there a clean way to control which columns are displayed in child rows? It seems to work with TEXT, but just not with TOGGLE.

A little later: There is a potentially useful function called gtk_cell_renderer_set_visible(), but it requires a reference to the cell renderer. How to acquire that on a per-row or per-cell basis when all I have during construction is the GtkTreeStore and a GtkTreeIter?

Comment: Please edit the question with a minimal working code example and it will greatly increase your chances of getting the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 solutions:

1. Base class `GtkCellRenderer` has `visible` property. You can add extra field to your model which indicates, whether Toggle should be visible for this row.
2. If there are *other* fields in you model which indicate whether it's a primary or secondary row but not directly you can use `gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func` to set a function to be called before rendering. There you can call `gtk_cell_renderer_set_visible` or any other function to set renderer's properties manually.